# Catalog_Product_Link table size

Tags: magento-1.8, database

The size of `catalog_product_link` in my magento database is 2.5 G with almost 22.7 million rows. My magento store has 190K products.

Is it normal to have such a large table for this number of products ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table contains all the relations between products

- cross-sells
- up-sells
- related products
- grouped products relation

So if you have a lot of these relations it's normal to reach that amount.

Comment: What about core_url_rewrite which is 2 G with 3M rows for this number of products ?

Comment: If you have the products in a lot of categories then magento will generate one rewrite for each combination of `product->category` and one for each product separately.